# failed to execute goal on project SpringWalkthrough, even though trying to run different project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

No idea what eclipse luna is doing. 
ive gone to run > run configurations > chosen base directory as ${workspace_loc:/HelloSpring}, chosen clean -e tomcat:redeploy as my goals and then hit apply and run.
f
Im getting the following error. 
Failed to execute goal on project SpringWalkthrough: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.fdmgroup:SpringWalkthrough:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springFramework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE, org.springFramework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE, com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0: (plus some more)

this is completely different project that I have closed. Its called SpringWalkthrough but why is Eclipse trying to do run or alter this when there is absolutely so need as it is not the project I want to be running.

Comment: can you see if it runs in commandline `mvn clean tomcat:redeploy` ? and it looks like you have org.springFramework:spring-core there. the group id should be all lowercase org.springframework

Comment: get the same errors in the cmd line as i do in eclipse

Comment: can you post your pom ?